# separating and adding the array data

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an array like this, which has the product selected data.

```
$option_data[] = array(
    'product_option_id'       => $product_option_id,
    'product_option_value_id' => $option_value,
    'name1'                   => $option_value['name'],
    'option_id'               => $option_query->row['option_id'],
    'option_value_id'         => $option_value_query->row['option_value_id'],
    'name'                    => $option_query->row['name'],
    'option_value'            => $option_value_query->row['name'],
    'type'                    => $option_query->row['type'],
    'quantity'                => $option_value_query->row['quantity'],
    'subtract'                => $option_value_query->row['subtract'],
    'price'                   => $option_value_query->row['price'],
    'sdate'                   => $option_value_query->row['sdate'],
    'edate'                   => $option_value_query->row['edate'],
    'price_prefix'            => $option_value_query->row['price_prefix'],
    'points'                  => $option_value_query->row['points'],
    'points_prefix'           => $option_value_query->row['points_prefix'],                                 
    'weight'                  => $option_value_query->row['weight'],
    'weight_prefix'           => $option_value_query->row['weight_prefix']
);
```

And I need the values for price, So I have assigned price value like this

```
$pricelist = $option_value_query->row['price'];
```

Actually it has two values , now I want to add those two values. I am not getting how to separate it and add those values.

EDITED ******

My function is like this

```
public function getProducts12() {

    if ($this->data) {

        foreach ($this->session->data['cart'] as $key => $quantity) {

            $product = explode(':', $key);
            $product_id = $product[0];
            $stock = true;
//echo $product_id;
            // Options
            if (isset($product[1])) {
                $options = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));

            } else {
                $options = array();
            } 

            $product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p.status = '1'");

            if ($product_query->num_rows) {
                $option_price = 0;
                $option_points = 0;
                $option_weight = 0;
foreach ($options as $option)
{

    $array123[] = $option;
    $var123 = $array123[0];

}

                $option_data = array();

                foreach ($options as $product_option_id => $option_value) {

                    $option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT po.product_option_id, po.option_id, od.name, o.type FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id) WHERE po.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "' AND po.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND od.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

                    if ($option_query->num_rows) {
                          if ($option_query->row['type'] == 'radio' ){
                            $option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT pov.option_value_id, ovd.name, pov.price, pov.sdate, pov.edate, pov.price_prefix, pov.points, pov.points_prefix, pov.weight, pov.weight_prefix FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value ov ON (pov.option_value_id = ov.option_value_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description ovd ON (ov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id) WHERE pov.product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$option_value . "' AND pov.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "' AND ovd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");     

                    if ($option_value_query->num_rows) {
                                if ($option_value_query->row['price_prefix'] == '+') {
                                    $option_price += $option_value_query->row['price'];

                                } elseif ($option_value_query->row['price_prefix'] == '-') {
                                    $option_price -= $option_value_query->row['price'];

                                }

                                if ($option_value_query->row['points_prefix'] == '+') {
                                    $option_points += $option_value_query->row['points'];
                                } elseif ($option_value_query->row['points_prefix'] == '-') {
                                    $option_points -= $option_value_query->row['points'];
                                }

                                if ($option_value_query->row['weight_prefix'] == '+') {
                                    $option_weight += $option_value_query->row['weight'];
                                } elseif ($option_value_query->row['weight_prefix'] == '-') {
                                    $option_weight -= $option_value_query->row['weight'];
                                }


                    $option_data[] = array(
                                    'product_option_id'       => $product_option_id,
                                    'product_option_value_id' => $option_value,
                                    'name1'                   => $option_value['name'],
                                    'option_id'               => $option_query->row['option_id'],
                                    'option_value_id'         => $option_value_query->row['option_value_id'],
                                    'name'                    => $option_query->row['name'],
                                    'option_value'            => $option_value_query->row['name'],
                                    'type'                    => $option_query->row['type'],
                                    'quantity'                => $option_value_query->row['quantity'],
                                    'subtract'                => $option_value_query->row['subtract'],
                                    'price'                   => $option_value_query->row['price'],
                                    'sdate'                   => $option_value_query->row['sdate'],
                                    'edate'                   => $option_value_query->row['edate'],
                                    'price_prefix'            => $option_value_query->row['price_prefix'],
                                    'points'                  => $option_value_query->row['points'],
                                    'points_prefix'           => $option_value_query->row['points_prefix'],                                 
                                    'weight'                  => $option_value_query->row['weight'],
                                    'weight_prefix'           => $option_value_query->row['weight_prefix']
                                );                              
                            }

                        //var_dump ($option_value_query->row['price']);

                        $pricelist = $option_value_query->row['price'];
                            //$_SESSION['m'] = $pricelist[0];

                          }
                    }
                }

var_dump($pricelist);
            } 
        }
    }


    //echo ($option_price);
    return $this->data;
    //echo $this->data;

}

}
```

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($pricelist);` ?

Comment: where are the two values? inside the one value of $price? if so - perhaps you can show some examples of $price?

Comment: How does it have two values? Is `->row['price']` comma separated or something?

Comment: @ DevlshOne: if i `var_dump($pricelist);`, it displays two values `127.00` and `166.00`

Comment: I have edited my post, have added the whole function. please check

Comment: Add complete (copy-paste) vardump of $pricelist

Comment: `string '166.0000' (length=8)
string '127.0000' (length=8)
string '166.0000' (length=8)
string '127.0000' (length=8)`

Comment: this is the `var_dump` result

Comment: I don't seem to recognize it as usual vardump output. What does `gettype($pricelist)` tell you?

Comment: `gettype($pricelist)` - in this nothing is getting displayed. Actually it is string

Comment: Sorry for not being completely explicit :) do `echo gettype($pricelist);`

Comment: ohh am so mad :( sorry, its giving `stringstringstringstring`

Comment: @Trogvar: i have converted those string values to integer by doing like this `$integerIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $pricelist));

        var_dump($integerIDs); `